# Mitsubishi Pajero (suv) 1992 v6 3000 Differential Oil Leak

Tags: oil-leak, mitsubishi, rear-differential, pajero

A few months ago I noticed that the rear differential was wet, with rigid oily soil.I used my screw driver to remove the stiff oily soil. the down part to the front of the car was wet. After removing the soil I saw that a hose or sealed wire entered the body of the differential from it's upper half the entry was also wet. Because this car has REAR DIFFERENTIAL LOCK I just guess that the seal of the entry might be damaged during course of that time, and something must be done with that? What else could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different „hoses“ enter diff case in Pajero. 1. air for diff lock, 2. diff breather hose. These 2 goes into the car body. 3. wiring which goes around the diff and then to the left arm and then it ends up with the wiring connector.
Oil from the diff can go into the breather and air line, but in tiny amounts. Usually diff leaks through front seal, or cracks in the housing (if you go offroad and doing it hard :) )

It's better to clean the diff with water drive a bit and then check what's happening :)